# UpdateCheckboxGroupInput in Shiny with R produces vroom error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to upload a csv file, and then `updatecheckboxGroupInput` with a column from the file. When I don't have the ui `checkboxGroupInput` or the `observeEvent`/`updateCheckboxGroupInput`, it works fine. But when I add those in, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in vroom::vroom: `file` is not one of the supported inputs:
• A filepath or character vector of filepaths
• A connection or list of connections
• Literal or raw input
122: \<Anonymous\>
121: signalCondition
120: signal_abort
119: rlang::abort
118: cli::cli_abort
117: standardise_path
116: vroom::vroom
115: read_csv
```

I don't understand why vroom is in the mix when I'm not using it, nor what it has to do with updating an input.

```r
library(shiny)
library(readr)
holiday_movie_genres <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-12-12/holiday_movie_genres.csv")

write.csv(holiday_movie_genres, "hmg.csv")
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("genre", "Select Genre", choices = NULL),
  fileInput("movie_file", "Upload File"),
  tableOutput("movie_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  movie_reactive <- reactive({
    read_csv(input$movie_file$datapath)
  })

  output$movie_table <- renderTable({
    movie_reactive()
  })

  observeEvent(movie_reactive(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(inputId = "genre", choices = unique(movie_reactive()$genres))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with</sup> [<sup>reprex v2.1.0</sup>](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the one you think. It is here:

```r
  movie_reactive <- reactive({
    read_csv(input$movie_file$datapath)
  })
```

Indeed, when the app starts, `input$movie_file$datapath` is `NULL`, hence the problem.

Do:

```r
  movie_reactive <- reactive({
    req(input$movie_file)
    read_csv(input$movie_file$datapath)
  })
```

Comment: ah hah! that's perfect, thanks!!! and i see it now, makes perfect sense. i think.